# Meaning of differentiability

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, terminology, differential-topology

Could anyone give an intuitive idea of the meaning of differentiability in general in any dimension and any space?

Comment: Having well defined tangent mapping.

Comment: Could you explain in details? @Berci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A differential map is a map than can be well approched by a linear map in a neighborhood of all points. The basic theorems in differential calculus (local form of immersions/submersions, implicit functions, local inversion) all give statements of the form: "we have a knowledge on the linear map that approaches the function (that is, its differential), then we have a local knowledge of the function itself".

Since linear algebra is much more simpler than analysis of functions, this explains why this idea is so important.